# How can i turn my query into an sequelize query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, crud

I have a query that i need to convert into ORM Sequelize (using MySQL as DB)

```
select departments.name_department, products.name, products.descricao, products.disponivel, products.destaque, produts.estoque
from products
inner join departments
on id_dep = departments.id
where id_dep = req.params
```

tried doing

```
async productByDep(req,res){
    const {id} = req.params;
    Departments.hasMany(Product, {foreignKey: 'id_dep'})
    Product.belongsTo(Department)
    Product.findAll({where: {id_dep : id}})
}
```

but i get a query completly different from the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to do it;

I used:

```
async productByDep(req, res) {
const { id } = req.params;
const products_dep = await Department.findAll({
  attributes: ['name_department'],
  include: [{
    model: Product,
    where: { id_dep: id },
    attributes: ['name', 'descricao','preco','estoque']
  }]
})
return res.json(products_dep)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You really have no control over the exact SQL query that Sequelize forms.
The main point of an ORM is so that you can get the data you want without having to think about the underlying SQL query.

Instead, you

1. define the models.
2. specify the associations between those models.
3. just add the `include` clause when you want to perform a join.

While writing the Sequelize query, you only think about what data you want. You do not think about the SQL query.
If you've defined the associations correctly, you'll most definitely get the correct data.
Have a look at the Sequelize docs on [Eager Loading](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html).

In your particular case, there will be two models - `Departments` and `Products`.

```js
const sequelize = require('sequelize');

// Define the models
const Departments = sequelize.define('Departments', {
  id: { type: sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  departmentName: DataTypes.STRING,
});

const Products = sequelize.define('Products', {
  id: { type: sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  name: sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
  id_dep: {
    type: sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: 'Departments',
      key: 'id',
    }
  }
});

// Define the associations between the models
// i.e. how the different models are related to each other
Departments.hasMany(Product, { foreignKey: 'id_dep' });
Product.belongsTo(Department);

// Query the data
Product.findAll({
  where: { id: req.params.id },
  include: Departments
});
```